# cakephp hasmanyandbelongsto and containable issue column not found

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have three tables business, category and business_has_categories.

```
business -> id, category_id, name, etc
category -> id, category_name, parent_id
business_has_categories -> id, category_id, business_id
```

In, all models i have public $actsAs = array('Containable'); so, i can use contain behavior

In category Controller, i have

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Business.status' => 1,
            'Category.slug' => some slug,
            'Business.suburb' => suburb,
            'Business.state' => $state,
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'BusinessCategory' => 'Category'
        ),
        'limit' => 20
    );

    $business = $this->paginate('Business');
```

when i run this, it gives me error Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Category.slug' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: SELECT `Business`.`id`, `Business`.`state`, `Business`.`slug`, `Business`.`city`, `Business`.`suburb`, `Business`.`user_id`, `Business`.`rating_id`, `Business`.`category_id`, `Business`.`business_name`, `Business`.`business_address`, `Business`.`business_postal`, `Business`.`business_postal_id`, `Business`.`business_phone`, `Business`.`business_phone1`, `Business`.`business_phone2`, `Business`.`business_email`, `Business`.`business_website`, `Business`.`business_details`, `Business`.`business_openinghours`, `Business`.`business_service`, `Business`.`business_addtionalinfo`, `Business`.`business_lat`, `Business`.`business_lng`, `Business`.`identity`, `Business`.`status` FROM `yuldicom`.`businesses` AS `Business` WHERE `Business`.`status` = 1 AND `Category`.`slug` = 'plumbers' AND `Business`.`suburb` = 'Acacia Ridge' AND `Business`.`state` = 'QLD' LIMIT 20

I noticed, there not included category table in the query

if i'm missing any thing

here code of each model

```
class Business extends AppModel {
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'BusinessCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'BusinessCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'business_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Rating' => array(
        'className' => 'Rating',
        'foreignKey' => 'business_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

}

```
class Category extends AppModel {
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $belongsTo = array(
    'BusinessCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'BusinessCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'Article' => array(
        'className' => 'Article',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Business' => array(
        'className' => 'Business',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'BusinessCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'BusinessCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

}

```
class BusinessCategory extends AppModel {
public $useTable = 'businesses_has_categories';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Business' => array(
        'className' => 'Business',
        'foreignKey' => 'business_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your database tables as per CakePHP’s conventions.

If you have a `Business` model and a `Category` model, and they have a “hasAndBelongsToMany” relation between each other, then your join table would instead be called `businesses_categories` (both model names pluralised and camel-cased, in alphabetical order, and separated with an underscore).

If you name your tables and models as per CakePHP’s conventions, then things like joins and relations will work out of the box as expected, without any need configuration needed from you. This is known as convention over configuration.

Your models, as a bare minimum, will then look like this:

```
<?php
class Business extends AppModel {

    public $uses = array(
        'Containable'
    );
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Category'
    );
}

class Category extends AppModel {

    public $uses = array(
        'Containable'
    );
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Business'
    );
}
```

Comment: i have recreated table structure and baked models again, model created fine. but now does not show [category] index in array

Answer (score 0):

It seems in the table structure, Business belongs to Category but I didn't see that in the Business Model. Why didn't you add that?

1. If you add that, it'll work and
2. make sure slug column is found in categories table.

Here it is the Business model should look like according to my suggestion (database structure)

```
class Business extends AppModel {
...
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);

...
}
```

Hope it helps!